# Please help to use ContourPlot for the locus (y - x^2) (y - 2 x^2) == 0. If I build the expression by hand, it shows nothing

Tags: plotting, expression

My code is as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq = (y - x^2) (y - 2 x^2) == 0;
branches = y /. Solve[eq, y];
Plot[branches, {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> eq]
eqExpand = eq // Expand;
tmp = eqExpand[[1, 3]] == -eqExpand[[1, 2]] - eqExpand[[1, 1]]
ContourPlot[y^2 == -2 x^4 + 3 x^2 y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

`Plot[]` works without problems. However, `ContourPlot[]` shows nothing when I use `tmp` (built in the previous line); I must write the expression by hand. I am unable to upload images at this time, will try later. Thx!

Comment: It is not clear why you are manipulating `eq` for the `ContourPlot`, rather than just using `ContourPlot[eq, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 200]`

Answer (score 0):

MMA 14.0 Windows 10

ContourPlot has some problems near the origin. PlotPoint improves it:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 == -2  x^4 + 3  x^2  y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2},  PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than my results, @Daniel Huber! My problem remains, however: If I substitute the expression with tmp, nothing is shown.

Comment: I get the same result using "tmp". Check what the value of tmp is. In my case it is `tmp`